# subscribe for orientation

Tags: navigation, simulation, odometry, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!I'm new to ros and i'm trying to get the orientation of a robot simulated in stage,so i've to subscribe to /odom,right?but i see that it has a lot of fields and i think that i only need the quaternion for the orientation,so how can i get this?and how can transform this into a theta?i've read the transform tf::getYaw,i must use this one?and in this case what should include in the code?thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30421/subscribe-for-orientation/) by [ldima](https://answers.ros.org/users/1979/ldima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-03-25**:
What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In answer to all of the little sub-questions you asked: Yes. To all of them. /odom isn't necessarily the globally-correct pose, though; see the REP about coordinate frames for details on that. Otherwise, you're spot on.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1